# local verses global pointer variables in this particular code

Tags: c, global-variables, binary-tree, local-variables

```
//binary tree
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* lc;
    struct node* rc;
    
}*ptr,*root;
void preorder(struct node* root){
    
    if(root!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",root->data);
        preorder(root->lc);
        preorder(root->rc);
    }
}

struct node* create(){
    int x;
    
    ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof( struct node ));
    
    printf("type data value(enter -1 if not needed):\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(x!=-1){
    ptr->data = x;
    printf("Left child of %d:\n",x);
    ptr->lc = create();
    printf("Right child of %d:\n",x);
    ptr->rc = create();
    return ptr;
    }
    else{
        
        return NULL;
    }

}

void main(){
    root = NULL;
    root = create();
    preorder(root);
}
```

This code above runs into an endless loop when executed. But when i declared the structure pointer variables locally instead of declaring it globally. It worked.
like this...

```
struct node* create(){
    int x;
    
   struct node* ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof( struct node ));
.......
void main(){
    struct node* root = NULL;
```

Can someone explain to me why does the above code run into endless loop and how did declaring the variables locally fixed it?

i was trying to implement a binary tree data structure using recursive function create()...
and the create function worked fine(i think) when i executed the code but the preorder() ran into an endless loop.

Comment: Your question is nigh-devoid of info. What loop is an end loop? The input loop in `create`? So that means your claiming that `x` isn't `-1` when you expect it to be `-1`. That could be because you expect `scanf` to succeed when it didn't.

Comment: by endless loop i basically meant the loop doesn't stop it just keeps on running indefinitely

Comment: I know what an endless loop is. Reread what I wrote. I asked *which* loop is running indefinitely? Why do you think it should exit? What's different than you expect that causes it to continue looping?

Comment: Im sorry i misread your earlier comment. the indefinitely running function is the preorder() function. create() works fine it reads the elements and stops once the user enters -1. but after create() in main function it calls preorder() which is supposed to print the preorder traversal of the tree entered and stop once its done. but instead it keeps on running indefinitely printing numbers until i use ctrl+c to exit the program on terminal.

Comment: The fact that you keep visiting valid pointers (since you're not crashing) would suggest that you are you continually visiting the same pointers, which is easy to verify with a print statement, and indicates an improperly built tree.

Answer (score 0):

`create()` is a recursive functions. And when you call `ptr->lc = create();` and `ptr` is a global variable, its value is overwritten by the recursive call and the assignment to `ptr->lc` is really made to *that* node.

Because of these traps you should really avoid using global variables in recursive functions (best: always avoid using global variables)